# Rails - Why does LINK_To Generate an unnecessary hit to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code:

```
<% @photos = Photo.where(:photo_album_id => storyitem.feeded_id).limit(4) %>

<%= link_to 'Image Set', project_photo_album_path(storyitem.project, @photos.first.photo_album_id) %>
```

In my logs, I see:

```
Photo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE ("photos"."photo_album_id" = 72) ORDER BY photos.created_at DESC, photos.version DESC LIMIT 1
Photo Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE ("photos"."photo_album_id" = 72) ORDER BY photos.created_at DESC, photos.version DESC LIMIT 4
```

After debugging, it's the link_to that is generating that extra database hit even though the first hit for 4 records finds the first query i need for the link_to.

Is there a way to prevent this query from hitting the db 2 times. I want just the query that gets a limit 4, which should give the app all the info it needs.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

I'd also like to be able to output the following:

```
<%=  @photos.first.photo_album.title %>
```

but that too hits the database again. Any way to hit the database only once for all of the above? thxs

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first hit occurs in code before what you are showing.

Are you sure the line

```
<% @photos = Photo.where(:photo_album_id => storyitem.feeded_id).limit(4) %>
```

hits the database? Because of lazy loading I think it's only when the second line is run that the database is hit.

I think you need to do more debugging to see where the first database hit occurs.

As for your update, change the first line to

```
<% @photos = Photo.where(:photo_album_id => storyitem.feeded_id).limit(4).includes(:photo_albums) %>
```

to load the photo albums in the same query.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look. What change the first line, what does that do?

Comment: Ah you're right! it doesn't hit the database until:::      <% @photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(photo.photo(:thumb)), photo_album_photos_path(photo.photo_album_id, :page => index + 1) %>
     <% end %>

Comment: but it still hits the db twice

Comment: I updated the first line. It's hitting the db four times now! yikes: Photo Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE ("photos"."photo_album_id" = 57) ORDER BY photos.created_at DESC, photos.version DESC LIMIT 1
  PhotoAlbum Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "photo_albums".* FROM "photo_albums" WHERE ("photo_albums"."id" = 57)
  Photo Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE ("photos"."photo_album_id" = 57) ORDER BY photos.created_at DESC, photos.version DESC LIMIT 4
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "photo_albums".* FROM "photo_albums" WHERE ("photo_albums"."id" = 57)

Comment: Hmm. Now I'm just guessing, but have you tried moving things around, like putting the include before the limit, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

```
<% @photos = Photo.where(:photo_album_id => storyitem.feeded_id).limit(4) %>
```

returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and it will not hit the DB until you call an `enumerable` method on it. Or alternatively you call `first`, `all` or `last` on it. Which is done in your second line,

```
<%= link_to 'Image Set', project_photo_album_path(storyitem.project, @photos.first.photo_album_id) %>
```

Where else in the code are you using `@photos`?

If you want to absolutely avoid a second call, just call the `all` method on `@photos`. Like this:

```
<% @photos = Photo.where(:photo_album_id => storyitem.feeded_id).limit(4).all %>
```

Then for all subsequent uses, it will not hit the DB again. If you further want to avoid a DB hit for `photo_album`, then you can use `include`:

```
<% @photos = Photo.where(:photo_album_id => storyitem.feeded_id).limit(4).include(:photo_albums).all %>
```

Comment: `all` will force the DB roundtrip. And load the query. `first` and `last` are just special cases of `all`.